# Assign same Integration Service to Multiple workflows in the same folder : any command or all-done-by-one process?

Tags: workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to assign the same IS to several workflows in Informatica PowerCenter 9.6.

Is there any way to do it by single go type command or any process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in informatica to change the integration service for all the workflows under a folder. Follow the below steps

Workflow manager --> Click on the folder --> Go to service tab -->Choose integration service --> Check the option "Select all displayed workflows" --> Then click assign

Attached a screenshot for reference

[image]
Hope it helps.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: Thanks a lot Raj. :)